# How to Update if a Row Exists on Another Table (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, exists

I am trying to update a column on a `itemTable` if a row with a matching `iid` exists on a correlated table.

`itemMeta` is a NoSQL style table, with duplicate `iid`s per item on the table, and `itemTable` is a relational table.

```
update itemTable it
set hasAttributes = (select
  case when select count(1) from itemMeta where (im.iid = it.iid) 
  then 'Y' 
  else 'N' end)
from itemMeta im
where (im.iid = it.iid)
```

How do I set the column to `Y` on `itemTable` if a row with a matching `iid` exists on `itemMeta`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What is wrong with your query?  What are you trying to update the value to?

Comment: Updated with SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work in most databases, including SQL Server:

```
update itemTable
    set hasAttributes = (case when exists (select 1
                                           from itemMeta im
                                           where im.iid = itemTable.iid
                                          ) 
                              then 'Y' else 'N'
                         end);
```

If you just want to update the value to `'Y'` if the value exists (and leave the existing value if present), then I would recommend:

```
update itemTable
    set hasAttributes = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from itemMeta im
                  where im.iid = itemTable.iid
                 );
```

This limits the rows being updated, so it should have better performance.

And, if you care about performance, you want an index on `itemMeta(iid)`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!